# How to create a dynamic WPF datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

i have a dynamic database whereby the data in the database will be updated within a minute. Now, i created a datagrid in my WPF project and i want to show all the data from the database. When i run my project, the datagrid will only show the static data(data before the project run). How can i make sure my datagrid will keep **update itself** after i run it? Btw, i using linq to sql and C# for my WPF project.

code snippet for my datagrid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="MyDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" >
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date"  Width="60" Binding="{Binding Date}" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Width="55" Binding="{Binding Time}"/>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="69" Binding="{Binding id}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

code snippet for my code behind:

```
public  MainWindow()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        using (MyDummyDataContext db = new MyDummyDataContext())
        {
            var query = from p in db.Ids
                        orderby p.Id descending
                        select new 
                        { 
                            Date = p.Date,
                            Time = p.Time,
                            id = p.Id
                        };
            MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = query;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my 2 cents:

1. Bind your DataGird's ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection.
2. Initialize the collection on the loaded event handler.
3. Add an timer, in the timer's callback, you can refresh the collection from database. Note：if you are using .NET 4.5, there is support for updating ObservableCollection form background thread. Otherwise, you need to handle the thread synchronization manually.

Here is a link for updating data in background, may be not perfect fit your problem, but you can get some ideas:

[Observable Collection Cross-Thread Change Notification](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/01/16/wpf-45-observable-collection-cross-thread-change-notification)

Edit:

I just wrote an example(For simplicity, I use DispatcherTimer which updates the collection in UI thread. To update data in background thread, you need to use System.Timers.Timer instead, and use the method in the link.):

App.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace DataGridTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow { DataContext = vm };
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="MyDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"  Width="60" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="55" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace DataGridTest
{
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Threading;

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _id;

    private string _name;

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._id == value)
                return;

            this._id = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this._name == value)
                return;

            this._name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        _timer.Tick += this._timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
        if(vm != null)
            vm.Refresh();
    }
}
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
namespace DataGridTest
{
  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
  using System.ComponentModel;

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Person> _persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    private static int _id = 3;

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get
        {
            return _persons;
        }
    }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _persons.Add(new Person { Id = 1, Name = "A" });
        _persons.Add(new Person { Id = 2, Name = "B" });
        _persons.Add(new Person { Id = 3, Name = "C" });  
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        _persons.Add(new Person() { Id = ++_id, Name = _id.ToString() });
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Mind if I ask why you would do something like this with a ObservableCollection? I understand that it might be good if you wish to have events if there was any need to run any methods when we update/delete records but it feels a little bit overkill at this stage. Never used a ObservableCollection so would be nice to know if I missed anything cool.